# Can a Pod Security Policy be applied to a namespace?

Tags: kubernetes

How can I apply a PSP (PodSecurityPolicy) only for the `kube-system` namespace and another PSP for all other namespaces?

Answer (score 2):

As we can read in the Kubernetes documentation about [Pod Security Policies](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/policy/pod-security-policy/).

> A *Pod Security Policy* is a cluster-level resource that controls security sensitive aspects of the pod specification. The `PodSecurityPolicy` objects define a set of conditions that a pod must run with in order to be accepted into the system, as well as defaults for the related fields.

You should use [RBAC](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/) and setup `Role` which will use desired `PSP`.

> If a `RoleBinding` (not a `ClusterRoleBinding`) is used, it will only grant usage for pods being run in the same namespace as the binding. This can be paired with system groups to grant access to all pods run in the namespace:

```
# Authorize all service accounts in a namespace:
- kind: Group
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  name: system:serviceaccounts
# Or equivalently, all authenticated users in a namespace:
- kind: Group
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  name: system:authenticated
```

You should also check out [Using PodSecurityPolicies](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/pod-security-policies) and [Kubernetes: Assigning Pod Security Policies with RBAC](https://medium.com/coryodaniel/kubernetes-assigning-pod-security-policies-with-rbac-2ad2e847c754).

Hope this helps.

Comment: FYI PSP are deprecated since Kubernetes 1.22. They are replaced by Admission Controllers https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/enforce-standards-namespace-labels/